# How to combine equals method in java and html link in jsp

Tags: jsp

If I want to write code for

```
if(("a").equals("a")) then
some html code i.e, link to hide(<a href="index.html"style="visibility:hidden"></a>)
```

How should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% if ("a".equals("a")){ %>
<a href="index.html"style="visibility:hidden"></a>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`el`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) ternary operator to apply that style if that condition is true, otherwise don't apply the style, like this:

```
<a href="index.html" ${ 'a' eq 'a' ? 'style="visibility: hidden"' : '' }></a>
```